# Giving priority to the div width

Tags: html, css

I use below divs by fixed `width`

```
<div width="715">
  <div style="width:40%;float:right">
  </div>
  <div style="width:5%;float:right">
    <img src="x.png" />
  </div>
  <div style="width:15%;float:right">
  </div>
  <div style="width:40%;float:right">
  </div>
</div>
```

5% of 715 = 35

my problem is that x.png is larger than 35 (`width`: 80)

What do you recommend a way to prioritize the div `width` ?

Comment: use max-width for the div or try using !important

Comment: What do you mean by 'prioritize the div width`? You want the image to be contained inside its parent?

Comment: I want image width equal to the amount to be father

Comment: how come `5% of 715` turns out to be  `35`

Comment: You need to set the png width to max-width:100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this markup `<div width="715">` is deprecated, so trying to understand what you want to achieve here is a snippet based on your code:

#### snippet

```css
.wrap {
  width: 715px
}
div[class*="div-"] {
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
}
.div-one {
  width: 40%;
  background: red
}
.div-two {
  width: 5%;
  background: green
}
.div-three {
  width: 15%;
  background: blue
}
.div-four {
  width: 40%;
  background: yellow
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div-one"></div>
  <div class="div-two">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
  </div>
  <div class="div-three"></div>
  <div class="div-four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set `Style=width:30%!Important` and also try to set the overflow  like this  `overflow: hidden;`
if that didn't work 
you should set max-width property to a fixed value so it won't expand

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> ```
> <div width="715">
> <div style="width:40%;float:right">
>
> </div>
> <div style="width:5%;float:right">
>   <div style="background:url('x.png');background-size: contain;"></div>
> </div>
> <div style="width:15%;float:right">
>
> </div>
> <div style="width:40%;float:right">
>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```